# Limit VirtualBox Internet Speed and Max bandwith usage

Tags: virtualbox

I am running a virtual version of windows inside of another version of windows using dropbox. I would like to be able to limit the bandwith usage and internet usage of this virtual machine. How woold I achieve this? Are there programxs that can limit the internet usage of a certain application, I am looking for a free program but a 14 day trail would also be enough for now if needed. The problem is someone is threatening to attack me and already did so before with some kind of login bot. This rapidly makes my diskusage grow. That's why I put it in the VM to be sure the server doesn't go over the max space usage of my real life hard disk, which could potentially break my computer. He has also DDOS me before and since the server is a small game server and doesn't use that much bandwith. I would like to limit its internet speed and total bandwith usage so that it could never go above my maximum internet usage of 100GB that my ISP enforces. Because that would put me personally without internet, which is a very big problem. I don't think there is an option for this in virtualbox itself. That's why I was hoping for a third party application that can limit applications internet usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use latest version with advanced command-line configuration:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bandwidth_limit